Does DTU Purchase Model have cold starts?
I'm pretty sure you guys are getting tired of my questions, but Azure's phone lines aren't working (according to the MS rep) and the information isn't clear. Screenshot below (in Spanish) from the MS sales rep:

Anyways, I would like to use an Azure SQL Database for a mobile app I want to publish in the near future.
I tried the "Provisioned" Compute Tier with the "vcore" Purchase Model, but the cheapest one (hyperscale) starts at $267/month. Then I tried the "serverless" Compute Tier, but the cold starts make the app unusable.
So my last option before moving away from Azure is the DTU Purchase Model with the Standard Service Tear at $14.72/month.
Is there a cold start or some other limitation to the Standard DTU plan?

It seems you are choosing S0 or S1 tier. If that is the case, regarding data storage, the Standard S0 and S1 service tiers are placed on Standard Page Blobs. Standard Page Blobs use hard disk drive (HDD)-based storage media and are best suited for development, testing, and other infrequently accessed workloads that are less sensitive to performance variability. Read more on the blue part on the Standard Tier documentation.
Another important constraint is vcores (processor resources). Up to S3 you will see your queries limited to use one vcore (MAXDOP = 1). On S4 your queries will be limited to 2 vcores. On S6 will be limited to 3 vcores.
Another major limitation is memory. S0 is limited to 262 MB of RAM. S1 is limited to 524 MB. S3 is limited to 8 GB.
In terms of costs, the DTU model is by far the cheapest Azure SQL option for a Production database. You do not pay for licensing fees.
